# How to get the binary path of a Mono process?

Tags: linux, process, mono-framework

Is it possible to get the path of a process running under Mono in Linux? For example if I launch KeePass using `mono KeePass.exe`, running `ps` just shows the command name as `mono`, while what I really want is `KeePass.exe`.

Comment: As far as I know, the process table records arguments. Try `ps ax | grep "mono"`.

Comment: @new123456: Great, this did the trick. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `ps ax | grep "mono"` - `ps` will show all processes and their arguments with the `ax` flag.